# error : collection has not been initialized on deleting an item from list

Tags: list, javascript, caml

Below is the function and its fetching the `Amount` and `uno` but it throws an exception on `clientContext.executeQueryAsync()`.

Here is the Code:

```
function delRec()

{
    var uno;
    var itemArray = [];
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    var i=1;
    var amount = 0;
    var oListItem;
    var d = new Date();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext())
    {
        oListItem= listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        if(document.getElementById('check'+i).checked==true)
        {
            amount=amount + oListItem.get_item('Amount');
            uno=oListItem.get_item('UniqueNo');
            alert(uno+' '+amount);
            oListItem.deleteObject();

            oListItem.update();

            itemArray.push(oListItem);

            clientContext.load(itemArray[itemArray.length-1]);
            alert(4);

        }
    }
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                                    function (sender, args)
                                    {
                                        alert('record updated succesfully');
                                        updateAmount(amount,uno);
                                        //location.reload(true);
                                    },
                                    function (sender, args)
                                    {
                                        alert('Error: ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
                                    });


}
```

Comment: It's because you have not loaded "collListItem" object. Please load that object before.

Comment: yes i have loaded collListItem and i am able to update and insert new item but it is failing in delete

Comment: If this is your code then ``collListItem`` is ``undefined``. If you expect us to be  psychic and know what you other code is, then I fear you will get a very low response rate here on StackOverflow

Comment: And by default I never answer questions using ``alert`` to debug code. If you want to call yourself a programmer, go and learn to use  the F12 Debugger Console... which... will help you find the errors yourself and save you from waiting for an answer here.

Comment: hey buddy thanks but i know f12 debugging(i have checked the value of collistitem)....if wanted specs u could have asked it ...instead of typing  rubbish.....thanks any way(i sorted it)

Comment: oh thank you man. I owe you this. If you were not there I would have never known what F12 is. You are bloody awesome. I am buying a new keyboard just with the F12 key on it. Wish you luck bro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the problem...it is because after deleting item listItemEnumerator is getting.movenext() results in exception.
changes made:

```
listItemEnumerator.moveNext();

                                                    while (listItemEnumerator.get_current())
                                                    {

                                                        oListItem= listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                                                        if(document.getElementById('check'+i).checked==true)
                                                        {
                                                            amount=amount + oListItem.get_item('Amount');
                                                            uno=oListItem.get_item('UniqueNo');
                                                            alert(uno+' '+amount);
                                                            listItemEnumerator.moveNext();
                                                            oListItem.deleteObject();
                                                        }
                                                        i++;                                                            i++;
                                                    }
                                                    oList.update();
```